# A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'db' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, sqflite

i am getting error

> A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'db' because it has a return type of 'Future'

for the code

```dart
    class DatabaseHelper {
      static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();
      factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

      static Database? _db;

      Future<Database> get db async {
        if (_db != null) {
             return _db;
      }
      _db = await initDb();
          return _db;
  }
   

     DatabaseHelper.internal();
    initDb() async {
         Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
     String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "main.db");
     var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
       return ourDb;
  }

  

    void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute(
              "CREATE TABLE User(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, password TEXT)");
        print("Table is created");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `db` isnot nullable type where `_db` is nullable. You can include `!` while you've already checked null state.

```dart
Future<Database> get db async {
  if (_db != null) {
    return _db!;
  }
  _db = await initDb();
  return _db!;
}
```

I recommend to check [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)